# Cannot access 'kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope' which is a supertype of 'androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleCoroutineScope'

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

Tried to use room api and had to deal with asynchronous tasks you know why.
I chose kotlin coroutines and androidx.lifecycle. Tried to write some code and got 2 errors displaying in IDE

Cannot access 'kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope' which is a supertype of 'androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleCoroutineScope'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Cannot access class 'kotlinx.coroutines.Job'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QpXH.png)

Here is my gradle module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'

}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jacksafblaze.sqlitedemo"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0"
    implementation'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0'
    implementation'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

and gradle project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried to invalidate caches and restart, to recreate app from scratch, and to reinstall android studio and I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

upgraded 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0' to
'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0-RC' and everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, if I manually add imports in the class the project will compile but the IDE will still display an error.

If you don't want to wait coroutines-android 1.6 release manually adding the import is a workaround, but you will have no autocompletion.

[Android Studio build without autocompletion example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss9TB.png)

You could also have some problems with room, moshi and all libraries that use kapt, you can try to update to latest release (beta/RC) to see if the problem will be fixed in new releases.

For example, when I am writing this lines, moshi is not compatible with kotlin 1.6 yet, and a fix is planed to be released as soon as possible, see [here](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1368) for details.